# how to make tables out for Spearman correlation table?

Tags: stata

I need to get a Spearman and Pearson correlation table using Stata. Here is what I did to get the results in a table format.

```
estpost correlate sp_rating srating mrating split split_neg split_ord split_neg_ord tier1_risk tier1_leverage st1 sl mt1 ml adt1 adl dt1 dl offering_amt maturity2 security 
enhance timeliness validity disc loan_at cash_dep trading_at real_est intangible other_at sec_sum assets_sold all_residual secinc_ta, matrix quietly

esttab . using "root4.rtf", replace notype unstack compress noobs nogaps nostar
```

Then, I get this error message:

```
varlist not allowed
```

When I used just a few variables, I didn't get the error, but when I put many variables. I don't know how to fix this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error and ran a `trace` on it. I believe this is a bug at line 946 of `estout.ado`, perhaps caused by the fact that a very long variable list with RTF tags exceeds the size of the local macro created at that line.

You should send a bug report to Ben Jann (email at the end of `help estout`). In the meantime, you can try saving to DOC and TXT, both of them might work (you have over 30 variables, I tested both `.txt` and `.doc` successfully with something like 20 variables).

Alternately, try the `mkcorr` command (`ssc install mkcorr`) to see if it works with your data.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after I tried a lot of different `esttab` outputs and had stored a lot in estimates.

So, maybe `estimates clear` helps if you type it before running your command. At least for me it worked.